# How do i play .mka audio in <video> tag

Tags: html

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="films/myfilm/video/1080p.mkv" type="video/webm">
  <source src="films/myfilm/audio/en.mka" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```

I serach google and i don't find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly play them using the video-tag. Your best option is to convert the files into a compatible format, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Otherwise, you have to use a plug-in like DivX to stream the formats to your browser:

http://www.divx.com/en/software/web-player/features

Comment: Whats best audio type to won't lose 5.1 audio ?

Comment: That's a whole different question haha, but I believe .mp4 allow 5., if converted with right settings (AC3). I'm no t an audio-expert sorry